# Videogular - video stops playing often - how to preload and indicate loading status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video, videogular

I have 86mb 1920x1080 video that I am playing online using videogular.

The video freezes often, taking 5-10 seconds to continue playing.

Is there a way to preload video completely and then play?

Is there a way to indicate how much has been loaded (as it's done on youtube?)

I've already tried `preload:"auto"`,`preload:"none"` and `preload:"preload"`.

Comment: Did you got the answer?

Comment: No, still no solution.